# How to send variable as a parameter to a method in single file component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to replace all `\n` with `<br>` in a variable. Why I can't send variable as a function parameter to a method from template? Console says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`.

I think it calls n2br method but can't send variable as a parameter.

Can anybody know how to solve this problem?

```
<template>
    <div id="iletisim" class="page">
        <div>{{ n2br(iletisim.address) }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "iletisim",
        data() {
            return {
                iletisim: ""
            }
        },  
        methods: {
        fetch: function() {
            this.$http.get(this.site.apiPath + this.site.currentLangCode + "/" +this.$route.params[1]).then(response => {
                this.iletisim = response.body.content;
            },
            response => {
            // error callback
            }); 
            n2br: function(text) {
                text = text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
                return text;
            }
        },
        beforeMount () {
            this.fetch()
        }       
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this is initially instantiated your 'iletism' data is a string.   The string does not have a property of address.   So iletism.address is undefined.

When that arrives to your n2br function it calls undefined.replace.  Which does not exist, hence the replace does not exist on undefined error.

So either guard for this in n2br method or set a default for iletism so that address exists but is empty string.

You could accomplish same thing with a computed property but same will be true that you will need a base case that is set in data or in the computed method.

Comment: nope. it is not a string. fetch part is taking care of its content.

Comment: When this is first ran it will be a string.  Check in a console.log to prove its value.

Comment: I added the fetch part to code of the question. Also I checked template with `{{ iletisim.address }}` and the value is correct.

Comment: Console.log in your n2br function.   On create this should pass in the empty string and the error will happen before the mount lifecycles you have.

Comment: I had to solve with `n2br: function(text = "")` to avoid first run error but I am not happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I don't think you need to send it honestly. Sounds like you need a computed property.

Lets say your fetch method sets data property `iletisim`.

In your template you would do this:

```
<div>{{ computedIletisim }}</div>
```

And then in your component after methods add computed

```
export default {
    ...
    methods: {
        ...
    },
    computed: {
      computedIletisim: function() {
        return this.iletisim.address.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
      }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I need to send because I have more than one variable to process (n2br)

Comment: Ok, I agree with @Austio you need to default it somehow because when the component mounts address doesn't exist because iletism is a string. Try setting iletism as an object in data and then in your method check if address is set. If you want to test this put console.log() in monted and log ilethism.

Comment: iletisim means "contact" in turkish by the way :)